Unhandled 'error' event with self-signed TLS certificate on node:http2 and wget
I created a simple HTTPS server with node:http2 package and self-signed certificate. This is a code for this app server:
import {createSecureServer} from 'node:http2';
import {readFileSync} from 'node:fs';

try {

    const server = createSecureServer({
        key: readFileSync('secure.key'),
        cert: readFileSync('secure.pem')
    });

    server.on('request', (req, res) => {
        req.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('Request error:', err);
            res.statusCode = 500;
            res.end('Internal Server Error');
        });

        res.on('error', (err) => {
            console.error('Response error:', err);
        });

        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.end('Hello World');
    });

    server.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Server error:', err);
    });

    server.listen(8443, () => {
        console.log('Server listening on port 8443');
    });

} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}

This is the key (secure.key):
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

This is the cert (secure.pem):
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

All works fine when I start the app:
/usr/bin/node server.mjs

and load the address https://grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com:8443/ with Chrome browser (you can use the local DNS to map the grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com to your localhost 127.0.0.1 for the tests):

But the server crashes when I try to open the address with wget:
$ wget --no-check-certificate https://grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com:8443/
--2024-08-30 08:33:02--  https://grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com:8443/
Resolving grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com (grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com)... 89.201.4.251
Connecting to grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com (grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com)|89.201.4.251|:8443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com,O=Test Bot,L=Bolderay,ST=Riga,C=LV’:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2024-08-30 08:33:02 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

The error on the console:
Server listening on port 8443
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Node.js v18.17.1

Process finished with exit code 1

The stack trace in the debug mode:
Uncaught Error: read ECONNRESET
__node_internal_captureLargerStackTrace errors:496
__node_internal_errnoException          errors:623
onStreamRead                            stream_base_commons:217
callbackTrampoline                      async_hooks.js:130
Async call from TickObject
init                                    node:in…pector_async_hook:25
emitInitNative                          async_hooks.js:202
emitInitScript                          async_hooks.js:504
nextTick                                task_queues:132
onDestroy                               destroy:103
Socket._destroy                         node:net:812
_destroy                                destroy:109
destroy                                 destroy:71
onStreamRead                            stream_base_commons:217
callbackTrampoline                      async_hooks.js:130
Async call from TLSWRAP
init                                    node:in…pector_async_hook:25
emitInitNative                          async_hooks.js:202
TLSSocket._wrapHandle                   node:_tls_wrap:623
TLSSocket                               node:_tls_wrap:523
tlsConnectionListener                   node:_tls_wrap:1110
emit                                    events.js:514
onconnection                            node:net:2038
callbackTrampoline                      async_hooks.js:130
Async call from TCPSERVERWRAP
init                                    node:in…pector_async_hook:25
emitInitNative                          async_hooks.js:202
createServerHandle                      node:net:1675
setupListenHandle                       node:net:1718
listenInCluster                         node:net:1799
Server.listen                           node:net:1887
(anonymous function)                    server.mjs:31
run                                     node:in…es/esm/module_job:194
Async call from await
(anonymous function)                    node:in…odules/esm/loader:525
Async call from Promise.then
import                                  node:in…odules/esm/loader:525
(anonymous function)                    node:in…/modules/run_main:58
loadESM                                 node:in…rocess/esm_loader:91
Async call from await
runMainESM                              node:in…/modules/run_main:55
executeUserEntryPoint                   node:in…/modules/run_main:78
(anonymous function)                    node:in…n/run_main_module:23

My question is how can I catch this exception in my nodejs app? Otherwise it turns out that anyone can take down my server using wget.
Thanks.
UPDATE:
There is no error when I use node:https:
import {createServer} from 'node:https';
...
    const server = createServer({
        key: readFileSync('secure.key'),
        cert: readFileSync('secure.pem')
    });

This is the wget call:
$ wget --no-check-certificate  https://grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com:8443/
--2024-08-30 14:33:47--  https://grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com:8443/
Resolving grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com (grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com)... 89.201.4.251
Connecting to grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com (grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com)|89.201.4.251|:8443... connected.
WARNING: cannot verify grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=grammy.dev.tg.teqfw.com,O=Test Bot,L=Bolderay,ST=Riga,C=LV’:
  Self-signed certificate encountered.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 11
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                             100%[==========================================================================>]      11  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2024-08-30 14:33:47 (2,85 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [11/11]

